# Can I create a load balancer for just a site hosted on s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a site hosted on s3, I do use cloudfront to control the http error codes returned. I have a `.app` domain that I would like to point at that site but I guess I need an `SSL` certificate for that and I heard Amazon has free ones if you use their load balancer.

So how do I go about setting up their load balancer to work with my S3 hosted site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard Amazon has free ones if you use their load balancer.

While that is true, you don't need -- and can't use -- a load balancer with an S3+CloudFront site.  Amazon Certificate Manager works directly with CloudFront, and no balancer is required in this configuration.  Certs are still free.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/amazon-cloudfront-integrates-with-aws-certificate-manager/

Comment: Oh cool, I'll take a look at that. I kind of stayed away from that since it sounded like it was for lots of certs and I really only need 1 or 2 tops.